# Remove all containers after certain location in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a process that adds div containers based on responses to questions.  The user has option to start over at any point.  I would like to remove all containers after a certain point when the user does this.  For example here is what you would see after 3 responses.

```
<div id="SolutionAdvisor">
    <div id="Col1"><div class="content">some content here</div></div>
    <div id="Col2"><div class="content">some content here</div></div>
    <div id="Col3"><div class="content">some content here</div></div> 
 </div>
```

If the user decides to go back to question 2 this what I would like to see:

```
  <div id="SolutionAdvisor">
    <div id="Col1"><div class="content">some content here</div></div>
    <div id="Col2"><div class="content">some content here</div></div> 
 </div>
```

I have tried using the :gt index like so:

```
     $('#SolutionAdvisor div:gt('+column+')').remove();
```

also tried:

```
     $('#SolutionAdvisor div:gt('+column+')').each(function(){$(this).remove();});
```

where column would be 1.

What I am seeing instead something like this:

```
 <div id="SolutionAdvisor">
    <div id="Col1"><div class="content">some content here</div></div>
    <div id="Col2"><div class="content">some content here</div></div>
    <div id="Col2"><div class="content">some content here</div></div> 
 </div>
```

What is proper way of doing this?

Comment: you have `prev` and `back` buttons?

Comment: Are you sure the `column` variable is what you think it is? And is it zero-based (as the jQuery `:gt()` is)? Could you maybe show a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: No, the questions have a series of drop down lists for responses.

Comment: Can you show how `column` is passed to you jQuery functionality?

Comment: @septemberbrain, i guess you code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/5x2Ct/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the list of children from the parent div as an array of html elements. Then, wrap each one in a jQuery call and remove them as follows:

```
var maxQuestions = 2;

 children = $('#SolutionAdvisor').children();
 for (var i = maxQuestions; i < children.length; i++) {
     $(children[i]).remove();
 }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenmtwhunt/YQusg/2/

There are some cool ways of doing this with jQuery selectors too, I just like the conceptual simplicity of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a direct descendant selector like:

```
$('#SolutionAdvisor > div:gt(?)).remove():
```

Also note that the value passed to `gt()` is zero-indexed.

Also, you might want to class those div's so you can get access them directly like:

```
$('.responses:gt(?)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best scenario to use .nextAll() method to capture all the elements that come after the entered value..

```
$('#txt1').on('change' , function() {
        var quesNo = $(this).val();    
        $('#SolutionAdvisor div:nth-child('+quesNo+')').nextAll().remove();        
    });
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/BAuJs/) here